# Vuejs otp next input

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I make an otp input with vuejs. I already set the max input to 1, so when the user enters an input, it will automatically move to the next input.

**Example:** https://codepen.io/danny1014/pen/NWRZOoO

```
<div v-for="(input,index) in pinLength" :key="index">
  <input type="text" maxLength="1" class="h-24 w-24 border-b border-white bg-transparent mx-2 text-center font-thin text-5xl outline-none focus:ring-0 text-white"></input>
</div>

data(){
    return{
      pinLength:4
    }
 }
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/ravishahesh/pen/WNobZvv

Comment: Great start, you might also want to add in support for backspace, left- and right arrow, copy/paste support perhaps.

Comment: thanks. but is there a way to access those values with v-models also? @RavishaHesh

Comment: I have updated the pen